# Search for Values in XML

Tags: php, xml

My XML

```
<properties>
<property>
    <refno>001</refno>
    <status>active</status>
    <type>SP</type>
    <description>Text Text Text</description>
    <images>
      <image>Path_here</image>
      <image>Path_here</image>
      <image>Path_here</image>
    </images>
</property>
<property>
    <refno>002</refno>
    <status>active</status>
    <type>SP</type>
    <description>Text Text Text</description>
     <images>
      <image>Path_here</image>
      <image>Path_here</image>
      <image>Path_here</image>
    </images>
</property>
</properties>
```

My PHP Code

```
if ($xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file_here)) {
    foreach($xml->property as $i) {
        if ($i->refno == "1") {
            echo $i->description."<br />".
            echo $i->type;
        }
    }
}
```

I normally loop though the XML to find a [refno] value. Is there a way to search for value without the need to loop?

Comment: You could wrap this logic into a function to return the element that matches, but this is the correct way already.

Comment: even if im looping for thousands of <property> nodes? Is there any other better and faster way? it makes the script execution slow.

Comment: What about a `if(strpos($your_xml_text, '<refno>12345</refno>') !== false) { // do stuff }` call over your XML **text** to quickly determine whether or not the element exists, then if it does you loop until you find it?

Comment: Do you just need the specific node(s), or the node(s) and it/their full hierarchy?

Comment: I need to get the siblings (status, type, description, images) of the matched <refno>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an XPath expression:

```
// find property element that contains a refno element with "001"
foreach ($xml->xpath('//property[contains(refno, "001")]') as $node) {
    echo (string)$node->description, "\n";
}
```

Comment: <refno> is unique, no duplicates

Comment: @Ratbucoh Well, `xpath()` returns an array of found elements; feel free to just pick the first one and skip the `foreach`.

Comment: @Ratbucoh since `refno` is unique, just assign it on a variable `$values = $xml->xpath('//property[contains(refno, "001")]'); $values = reset($values);` you got yourself the values. this already the correct answer